# django path showing twice in url bar

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm using django to make a little weather app for uni and I'm trying to link from the index page to a 'detail' page but in the url the path keeps apearing twice...

I've tried rewriting out the entire `urls.py` page (both of them). I've looked online as well but there dosent seem to be much about this (or I'm not looking in the right places)

so when I click on 'more info' for day 1 the url bar shows `/day1/day1` instead of just `/day1`

[urls.py]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('weather.urls')),
    path('day2/', include('weather.urls')),
    path('day1/', include('weather.urls')),
]
```

[urls.py 2]

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('day1/', views.day1, name='day1'),
    path('day2/', views.day2, name='day2'),

]
```

[views.py]

```
def day1(request):
    return render(request, 'weather/day1.html')

def day2(request):
    return render(request, 'weather/day2.html')
```

[link tag in main html page]

```
<a href="{% url 'day1' %}">day 1</a>
```

Comment: Please include code fragments, *not images* of code fragments.

Comment: Your urls.py would help

Comment: sorry all, this (as you can probably tell) is my first question asked. I have replaced images with snippets. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Your main urls.py already has the path prefixes `day1/` & `day2/` so don't include those prefixes again in the secondary urls.py. See official documentation on how to include secondary urls.py - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: Ah oh my god... that's so simple!! Thanks you so much!